Can a customer sue a manufacturer in the customer's county if the manufacturer is in a different county?
A customer purchases an item from Amazon which develops a fault within the warranty period but the manufacturer refuses to repair it. The customer lives in a different county to the manufacturer but both are in California. Can the customer sue the manufacturer in a small claims court in the customer's county?

Questions asking for legal advice (i.e. advice which is specific to your circumstances) are off-topic here. I edited it to make it generic and to remove irrelevant details about the nature of the item's fault. It's quite a heavy edit, so feel free to rollback if you don't like it but be aware that if you do the question is likely to get closed.


Can a customer sue a manufacturer in the customer's county if the
manufacturer is in a different county?

This is often possible when the only remedy sought is money damages and the amount in controversy is under the $12,500 jurisdictional limit for small claims courts in California.
Every California court has jurisdiction over defendants based on California, and if the amount in controversy is small enough, you can sue for money damages in small claims court.
The only real issue is which county would be a proper venue for the lawsuit. This is governed by California Code of Civil Procedure § 395.5 which says:

A corporation or association may be sued in the county where the
contract is made or is to be performed, or where the obligation or
liability arises, or the breach occurs; or in the county where the
principal place of business of such corporation is situated, subject
to the power of the court to change the place of trial as in other
cases.

You can sue in small claims court where the manufacturer is located. But, you might be able to sue elsewhere as well.
The difficulty is localizing "where the contract is made or is to be performed, or where the obligation or liability arises, or the breach occurs[.]"
If the item is delivered to your home, and ordered from your home, there is certainly a good argument that the contract is made and to be performed in your home, and that the obligation or liability arises at your home where the item fails to work there.
In one chestnut of a case confirming that thought, the California Supreme Court affirmed a trial court ruling that venue was proper in Santa Clara County, where the goods purchased were delivered and used and their defective quality was revealed, in Santa Clara County, rather than the county where the manufacturer was located. The facts were as follows:

The defendant in this action is a California corporation, having its
principal place of business in the city and county of San Francisco.
The action was commenced in the county of Santa Clara to recover
damages for breach of warranty of the quality and fitness of certain
galvanized sheet iron which it was alleged was sold and delivered by
the defendant to the plaintiff is said county of Santa Clara.

Cook v. W.S. Ray Mfg. Co., 115 P. 318, 318–19 (Cal. 1911).
It appears that this case is still good law.
